# CSS float:left and overflow:visible cutting off text

Tags: javascript, css, css-float, overflow

I'm currently trying to make a color gradient in javascript with numerical values in some of the divs to represent as the scale. However, I've noticed with larger values, the numbers get cut off due to the float:left. I've also tried used display:inline-block, but it seems that has weird positioning and leaves gaps between them. I need the divs flush together, but just have the text overflow ontop of the following div. Is there a way to do this?

Both examples I mentioned are here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3LTZ/3/

```
<div style="overflow: visible; width: 600px; height: 30px;white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="width:20px;height:100%;overflow: visible;display:inline-block;background-color:red;">texts</div>
    <div style="width:20px;height:100%;overflow: visible;display:inline-block;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="width:20px;height:100%;overflow: visible;display:inline-block;background-color:red;">texts</div>
    <div style="width:20px;height:100%;overflow: visible;display:inline-block;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="width:20px;height:100%;overflow: visible;display:inline-block;background-color:red;">texts</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div style="overflow: visible; width: 600px; height: 30px;white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="width: 20px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:red;">texts</div>
    <div style="width: 20px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="width: 20px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:red;">texts</div>
    <div style="width: 20px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="width: 20px;height:100%;float:left;background-color:red;">texts</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help a lot if you could describe what exactly you want it to look like. Are you trying to make a striped background or something?

Comment: [Here's a modification of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kE2pr/) to make the `inline-block` version work the same as the `float` version, but I still don't get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/nhFX2/)

using inline-block

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="single-block red">texts</div>
    <div class="single-block green"></div>
    <div class="single-block red">texts</div>
    <div class="single-block green"></div>
    <div class="single-block red">texts</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    width: 600px; 
    height: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:0;
}
.single-block{
   width:20px;
   height:100%;
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:bottom;
    font-size:16px;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text overlap the following div, you have to give them `position:absolute;`

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: visible; width: 600px; height: 30px;white-space: nowrap;">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="textontop">texts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="textontop">texts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="textontop">texts</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.column {
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    overflow: visible;
    float:left;
    z-index:0;
}

.textontop {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/y3LTZ/5/

Comment: This worked well for me, thank you. However I accepted the other proposed answer because it didn't rely on position:absolute so it made other layouts on the page easier. Thank you though! Will upvote when I can